# How do I launch my game on steam via script?

Tags: bash, game-development, steam

I've uploaded my game to steam and trying to make it work on windows, linux and macos. I've got macos working
and now I'm trying to get linux working.

I'm writing my game in bevy (rust) and using the bevy_steamworks plugin to connect to the steam api which means I have set up the path to "libsteam_api.so". I've included "libsteam_api.so" in the zip file I uploaded
and I've set steam to launch this script when you press play:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="."
./glow "$@"
```

The script works great when I run it via the terminal but when launching through Steam the game exists immediately. Is there a better approach without a script or is there some simple error in my script?

Comment: I don't know anything about making games, but do you get any kind of log from the Steam client about the failed startup? If not, I'd try something like `./glow "$@" >/tmp/SomeFile 2>&1` to see whether `glow` outputs anything. Also, inside your script, running something like `ldd` on the executable file and redirecting the output to a file should let you see whether shared libraries are found.

Answer (score 0):

I made a slight modification to the script to let the game get the same process ID as the script but the real problem was that the game and executable were nested in a subfolder. So the `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="."`
the path was wrong. I removed the unnecessary folder and lifted everything up one step and now it works :)

Modified script:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="."
exec ./glow "$@"
```